# Google Cloud Storage Code not working

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

After everything was created in Google Cloud below code was written to upload images from my server to google cloud but i am getting error with google storage class

My upload_gcs.php code below

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException;

if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['error']== 0) {
$allowed = array ('png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg');
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array(strtolower ($ext), $allowed)) {
echo 'The file is not an image.';
die;
}

$projectId = 'photo-upload-205311';

$storage = new StorageClient ([
'projectId' => $projectId,
'keyFilePath' => 'Photo Upload-3af18f61531c.json'
]);

$bucketName = 'photo-upload-205311.appspot.com';
$bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);

$uploader = $bucket-> getResumableUploader (
fopen ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r'),[
'name' => 'images/load_image.png',
'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',
]);

try {
$uploader-> upload ();
echo 'File Uploaded';
} catch (GoogleException $ex) {
$resumeUri = $uploader->getResumeUri();
$object = $uploader->resume($resumeUri);
echo 'No File Uploaded';
}
}
else {
echo 'No File Uploaded';
}
```

Error which i am getting is below

```
> Warning: The use statement with non-compound name
> 'GoogleCloudStorageStorageClient' has no effect in upload_gcs.php on
> line 4
> 
> Fatal error: Class 'StorageClient' not found in upload_gcs.php on line
> 16
```

Is my process correct or are there any other ways to upload image from my server to google cloud storage.

Comment: The error “Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient' not found in ” suggest the [Storage Client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php) is not installed.
Have you take a look at the samples in [using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-storage) and [simple file write](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/#simple_file_write)? They may help you get started using PHP with GCS.

Answer (score 0):

The correct namespace for the script has to be used otherwise it's unresolvable. See correction below.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\GoogleException;

class GCPStorage {
    function __construct()
    {
        $projectId = '<your-project-id>';
        $bucketName = '<your-bucket-name>'; 
        $storage = new StorageClient([
            'projectId' => $projectId,
            'keyFilePath' => '<your-service-account-key-file>'
        ]);

        $this->bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    }

    function uploadToBucket()
    {
        if(/your-precondition/) {
            return 'No File Uploaded';
        }

        $uploadedFileLocation = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $uploader = $this->bucket->getResumableUploader(
            fopen($uploadedFileLocation, 'r'),
            ['name' => 'images/file.txt', 'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead']
        );
        try { 
            $object = $uploader->upload();
        } catch(GoogleException $ex) {
            $resumeUri = $uploader->getResumeUri();
            try {
                $object = $uploader->resume($resumeUri);
            } catch(GoogleException $ex) {
                return 'No File Uploaded';
            }
        } finally {
            return 'File Uploaded';
        }
    }
}

$gcpStorage = new GCPStorage;

echo $gcpStorage->uploadToBucket();
```

> A small suggestion: assert your precondition early as a guard clause by returning early when it fails.

Comment: its saying this error : Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient' not found in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\googleupload\upload_gcs.php on line 16

Comment: I already placed my code in above tag at top which is commented with some hash code. can you please check and help me.

Comment: Format the code so that it's readable. What you have there are instructions written in an interpreter and I don't see a line 16 in any place

Comment: With the code which was given above i am getting fatal error with this class StorageClient